# Redirect http to https using apache mod_proxy

Tags: apache, mod-proxy, proxypass

---

### **Setup**

appserver   ----> webserver   ----> (3rd party endpoint)

> ```
>       8080              (https://www.b2b.com:1100/...)<br/>
>      [http]      [https]
> ```

---

### **Error Logs**

[Mon Nov 19 17:18:23 2012] [warn] Proxy client certificate callback: (box1:80) downstream server wanted client certificate but none are configured
[Mon Nov 19 17:18:23 2012] [error] (502)Unknown error 502: proxy: pass request body failed to :1100 (www.b2b.com)
[Mon Nov 19 17:18:23 2012] [error] proxy: pass request body failed to :1100 (www.b2b.com) from box1()

---

### **Issue**

The 3rd party upgraded their env and provided revised certs (rootCA, intermediateCert, serverCert)

The older implementation had only one self signed cert.
We had used mod_proxy to redirect http to https.
Used virtualhost and used SSLProxyEngine config the cert and it was working fine

After the upgrade of the 3rd party, the existing configuration no longer works and we receive a http-502 error

Any pointers on configs that needs to be included on apache side?

---

### **Old Configuration**

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so

```
<VirtualHost [ip]:8080>
ServerName hostname.com
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.crt"
#SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
#SSLProxyCheckExpire on
ProxyPass           /outboundservice/b2b/ https://www.b2b.com/webservice/7/
ProxyPassReverse    /outboundservice/b2b/ https://www.b2b.com/webservice/7/
```

### **New Configuration**

```
<VirtualHost [ip]:8080>
ServerName hostname.com
SSLProxyEngine On
SSLCertificateFile "conf/ssl.crt/cons_v8.cer"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "conf/ssl.crt/server.key.pem"
#SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
#SSLOptions +ExportCertData
#SSLProxyVerify Optional
LogLevel debug
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass           /outboundservice/b2b/ https://www.b2b.com/webservice/8/
ProxyPassReverse    /outboundservice/b2b/ https://www.b2b.com/webservice/8/
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks
-R